# Render form from partial when object invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, renderpartial

On my landing page i have a contact form

```
<%= render 'contacts/form' %>
```

Everything works great when object is valid. But i have a problem with render this contact form on my landing page with information whats attributes are wrong.

**This is my controller:**

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
    if @contact.save
      redirect_to root_url
      flash[:success] = "Dziękuję za wysłanie wiadomości"
    else
      render 'homes/home'
    end
  end

  private

  def contact_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:podpis, :wiadomosc, :email, :nickname)
  end
end
```

**My homes/home template:**

```
  <div id="page-content">

  <!-- O mnie -->
  <%= render 'o_mnie' %>         

  <!-- Resume -->
  <%= render 'resume' %>

  <!-- Blog -->
  <%= render 'blog' %>

  <!-- Portfolio -->
  <%#= render 'projekty' %>  

  <!-- Contact -->
  <%= render 'kontakt' %>

</div>
```

**This is my application layout**

```
<body>
     <%= render 'layouts/header' %>

    <div id="page-content">
        <%= render 'shared/flashes', flash: flash %> 
    </div>

    <%= yield %>
</body>
```

When i check on stack similar problems, now i know that the problem laying in render 'homes/home'. This gives me errors

> Missing partial contacts/_o_mnie, application/_o_mnie with {:locale=>[:pl], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in:

When i try render root_url, i have the same problem.
What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the template is used by other controller, you have to specify the prefix.

Change to:

```
<div id="page-content">

  <!-- O mnie -->
  <%= render 'homes/o_mnie' %>         

  <!-- Resume -->
  <%= render 'homes/resume' %>

  <!-- Blog -->
  <%= render 'homes/blog' %>

  <!-- Portfolio -->
  <%#= render 'homes/projekty' %>  

  <!-- Contact -->
  <%= render 'homes/kontakt' %>

</div>
```

Comment: Thx this help me, now im on top of my landing page. Do you know how i can render landing page but view will be on my contact form?
Something like  <%= link_to "resume" root_path(anchor: "resume")  %>

Answer (score 1):

Consider your files(`_o_mine.html.erb`,`_resume.html.erb`, `_blog.html.erb`,`_kontakt.html.erb`) are in `/app/views/shared` folder

then it will be something like this

```
<div id="page-content">

  <!-- O mnie -->
 <%= render 'shared/o_mnie' %>         

   <!-- Resume -->
 <%= render 'shared/resume' %>

 <!-- Blog -->
 <%= render 'shared/blog' %>

  <!-- Portfolio -->
 <%#= render 'shared/projekty' %>  

 <!-- Contact -->
 <%= render 'shared/kontakt' %>

 </div>
```